# Send data to Excel file using DDE

Tags: c#, excel-2016, dde

I know DDE is old fashion outdated technology. But I am creating a C# Windows Form application to send data to Excel file for research purpose. I use Win32 DDE functions and below is what  I have tried so far.

**Pinvoke signatures:**

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "DdeInitialize")]
public static extern int DdeInitialize(out uint pidInst, IntPtr pfnCallback, IntPtr afCmd, IntPtr ulRes);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "DdeConnect")]
private static extern IntPtr DdeConnect(uint idInst, IntPtr hszService, IntPtr hszTopic, IntPtr pCC);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "DdeCreateStringHandle")]
private static extern IntPtr DdeCreateStringHandle(uint idInst, string psz, int iCodePage);

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Process application = new Process();
    application.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\DDE_Client.xlsx";
    application.Start();
    uint instId;
    DdeInitialize(out instId, application.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

    IntPtr sPtr = DdeCreateStringHandle(instId, "Excel", 1004);
    IntPtr tPtr = DdeCreateStringHandle(instId, "Sheet1", 1004);

    IntPtr channel = DdeConnect(instId, sPtr, tPtr, (IntPtr)null);
}
```

DdeConnect returns non-zero value which indicates the connection is successful.

**My question:**

How to send a string value to the excel sheet? For example, I want to send "Name" to excel cell A1. Which DDE function should I use for the task?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use DDEML and it is indeed hard to find decent DDEML examples because many people who actually needed to use DDE had done so directly using raw Windows Messages.
You will have to first start  client transaction using *[DdeClientTransaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ddeml/nf-ddeml-ddeclienttransaction)* and then corresponding api like DdeGetData or DdeAddData, DdeAccessData etc to access or get the data.
You can find more details about DDEML in the MS Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dataxchg/dynamic-data-exchange-management-library).

But since you are already using C# I highly recommend that it would be much better to just add a reference to the Microsoft Excel or Office Object Library  in COM Assemblies section and use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 
Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```